# Bash for loop return null stop program?

Tags: bash, for-loop, int

I'm making a script which search for files, and count em. Later, i'm using this count value to create backup files. This is what it looks like :

```
#!/bin/sh
#LOCAL VAR PERFECTLY DEFINED



 if $estdifferent ; then 
        x=0;
        for fic in `find $OTHERDIR/liste/ -type f -name "${filename}_bak*"` ; do
        {

            filename_tab[x]=$fic
            ((x++))
        }
        echo "tableau rempli, nombre de fichier bak : "$x
```

This codeblock works when "find" find at least one file, but not when there's 0 files.
The script is not reaching the last "echo". Debug mode stops script at :

```
echo differents
differents
true
x=0
find /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/scan-configs/liste/ -type f -name 'IDF-952584-S...
```

Why ?

Comment: What flavor and version of `/bin/sh` is this? That's not valid `bash` syntax. A `for` loop looks like `for ... ; do ... done`, not with the `{ ... }` block.

Comment: Bash 4.1.2(1) for redhat.
This 'for' syntax is working when a file is found :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replace :

```
for fic in `find $OTHERDIR/liste/ -type f -name $filename"_bak"*`;do
{
    echo $fic
    filename_tab[x]=$fic
    ((x++))
}
```

by

```
for fic in `find $OTHERDIR/liste/ -type f -name $filename"_bak"*` ; do
    echo $fic
    filename_tab[x]=$fic
    ((x++))
done
```

please ?

Comment: Debug says : 
++ find /tech/gtr/scripts/osm/scan-configs/liste/ -type f -name
find: missing argument to `-name'

But it says too, a few line upper that my $filename var is not empty

Comment: @user2564494 That should indicate your problem. It's not that `find` isn't finding anything - the `*` character in your pattern is being seen by the shell and expanded. Try using `-name "${filename}_bak*"` instead, as quoting prevents glob expansion.

Comment: My find looks like : 
for fic in `find $OTHERDIR/liste/ -type f -name "${filename}_bak*"` ; do

But again, with or without shopt -s nullglob, the script stops at this find.

Comment: @user2564494 You might want to fix the code posted in your question, then, because it definitely does not look like that...